# Cocoon, nested fields inside nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a project, with a Project Model, Main Groups Model and Trades Model, then each project can have many Main Groups, then each Main Group can have many Trades.

I can create the project and the main groups but the Trades are not saving.

project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :consultants
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :consultants, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :contractors
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contractors, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    has_one :client
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client

    has_many :main_groups
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_groups, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    has_many :trades, through: :main_groupsp
end
```

trade.rb

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :main_group
end
```

main_group.rb

```
class MainGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  has_many :trades
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trades, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Main Group From Partial:

```
.nested-fields.add-tasks
    .row
        .col-md-12
            .form-horizontal
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading 
                        Main Group
                    .panel-body
                        .form-group
                            = f.label :name, :class => 'col-sm-1 control-label'
                            .col-sm-11
                                = f.input :name,:label => false, input_html:{class: "form-input form-control"}
                        .form-group
                            = f.simple_fields_for :trades do |trade|
                                = render 'projects/forms/trade_fields', f: trade
                        .trade-links.form-group
                            .col-md-12
                                = link_to_add_association 'Add Trade', f, :trades,  :partial => 'projects/forms/trade_fields', class: "btn btn-default add-button pull-right btn-success"
                        .form-group
                            .col-sm-12
                                = link_to_remove_association 'Remove Main Group', f,class: "btn btn-default pull-right btn-danger"
```

Trade Form Partial:

```
.nested-fields.add-tasks
    .row
        .col-md-12
            .form-horizontal
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading 
                        Trade
                    .panel-body
                        .form-group
                            = f.label :name, :class => 'col-sm-1 control-label'
                            .col-sm-11
                                = f.input :name,:label => false, input_html:{class: "form-input form-control"}
                        .form-group
                            = f.label :cost, :class => 'col-sm-1 control-label'
                            .col-sm-11
                                = f.input :cost,:label => false, input_html:{class: "form-input form-control"}
                        .form-group
                            = f.label :start_date, :class => 'col-sm-1 control-label'
                            .col-sm-11
                                = f.input :start_date,:label => false, input_html:{class: "form-input form-control"}
                        .form-group
                            = f.label :end_date, :class => 'col-sm-1 control-label'
                            .col-sm-11
                                = f.input :end_date,:label => false, input_html:{class: "form-input form-control"}
                        .form-group
                            .col-sm-12
                                = link_to_remove_association 'Remove Trade', f,class: "btn btn-default pull-right btn-danger"
```

Comment: As I can see, `Project` has a many to many relation with `Trade`. But the relation is only defined in `Project` model. Not in the `Trade` model. In `Trade` model there must be `has_many :projetcs, :through => :table_name`

Comment: @Emu you should write that as answer :)